# How can I locate this span element in python with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, automation

everybody
I'm learning selenium in python,and I tried to locate this span element

`driver.find_element_by_tag_name('span')`

But there are so many ,how can I just locate this one?
The characters below are Chinese,you can use 'xxxxxxx' for substitution in your answer.
And due to the website limitation,I can only open the website in IE8,Firefox don't work because of the Java plugin.So I think I can't use Xpath.
I cant upload photo,so there's the link of the screenshot for the sourcecode,
Sorry for my poor English

[the source code is in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2BhS.jpg)

Comment: @Mohsin Awan, Please don't hunt for reputation, Do some meaning full edit. If some question missing the tag which it should required then only retag. But all time it not necessary to edit all the question for one common tag

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@unselectable='on']")
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'XXXXXX']")
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium's normal behavior is that it locates the first instance of the element if there are duplicates. It would be better if you locate and element by it's css selector or xpath if you want to find a specific element.

`driver.find_element_by_css_selector('<insert selector>')`

`driver.find_element_by_xpath('<insert xpath>')`

Comment: due to the website limitation,I can only open the website in IE8,Firefox don't work because of the Java plugin.So I think I can't use Xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

You can use the following `xpath` to locate the element-

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='x-tree-node-anchor' and @tabIndex='1']/span"));
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: due to the website limitation,I can only open the website in IE8,Firefox don't work because of the Java plugin.So I think I can't use Xpath.